# can someone please verify my answer for this sum of product

Tags: logic

Reduce each of the following expression to a minimum sum of products.  Show each step.

a) $g  =  w \bar{y} +  w x y  +  w y z  +  \bar{w} x y  +  w x \bar{y}$ (3 terms, 7 literals)

$W \bar{Y} + W X \bar{Y} + [W X Y + \bar{W} X Y] + W Y Z$

$W \bar{Y} + W X + W Y Z$

B) $f = x\bar{y}\bar{z} + x\bar{y}\bar{z} + x\bar{y}z + xy\bar{z}+ xyz$ (2 term, 3 literals)

$[\bar{X}\bar{Y}\bar{Z} + XYZ] + X\bar{Y}\bar{Z} + X\bar{Y}Z + XY\bar{Z}$

$XZ(\bar{Y}+ Y) + X\bar{Y}Z$

$XZ + X\bar{Y}Z$

$\bar{Y} + XZ$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The first looks okay, but I can't follow the second because of the weird formatting.

Answer (score 0):

a) Since your are asked to show each step. I think you should show more steps here. There is no traces of what you actually did ( the parenthesis do not really help to see what happens).

I would go for something more like:

\begin{align}
g  &= & w \bar{y} +  w x y  +  w y z  +  \bar{w} x y  +  w x \bar{y}\\
& = & w \bar{y}( true +  x) +  (w+\bar{w}) x y  +  w y z  \\
& = & w \bar{y} +  xy +  w y z  
\end{align}
Which is what you get (except that you have a tipo no?)

B) For the second one I think you typed it wrong. Is it:
$f = x\bar{y}\bar{z} + x\bar{y}\bar{z} + x\bar{y}z + xy\bar{z}+ xyz$ (2 term, 3 literals)
or
$f = {\bf\bar{x}}\bar{y}\bar{z} + x\bar{y}\bar{z} + x\bar{y}z + xy\bar{z}+ xyz$ (2 term, 3 literals)?

From your answer I assume it is the latter. However I get a different answer ($x+\bar{y}\bar{z}$). Can you edit your question with every step you took to see which is the good answer?

Comment: Thanks i'll type the answer correctly later as im in class right now. but i got the correct answers.